# how to find who links to your website using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i want to extract the website links which are using my website url in their domain .
i want a python code of it.

i tried this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.9skips.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
external_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for link in external_links:
    if link['href'].startswith('http'):
        print(link['href'])
```

but it is giving me only the internal links.
i want to get the links of other domain where my 9skips url is used.

Comment: For who, aren't there logs that record that?

Comment: for building an my own api to do so

Comment: Please add some more details to clarify - The url you are requesting do not have any external links, so result would become empty or shows only internal one. If you are dealing with backlinks, I am with @SolarMike there should be an log / plugin from press / wordpress that deals with this point or  you have to switch to an url that has any backlinks.

Comment: lets take i am the owner of the domain www.mydomain.com   , i want to know which website used my www.mydomain.com inside their websites. like for refernece or any other purposes .....for do so.. i want a python code

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, better check your server logs / plugins for referrer or backlinks, else you have to write or use a crawler. Think your intent could not be answered in a few lines, because it is not clear what is the focus, alist of urls only or the whole internet.

Answer (score 1):

*Take the comments in mind, there are better options, based on small amount of information provided in the question.*

However, if you have a specific set of urls you will request, you could go with the following [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('a[href*="mydomain"]')
```

**Note:** *As mentioned, this could result in an empty `ResultSet` in many ways, cause there are no external links, they are masked, ... So better take a look into your logs*